# Optimization for many markers on Google Map ios sdk?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm using the following code to see when markers enter the screen :

```
let visibleRegion = mapView.projection.visibleRegion()
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(region: visibleRegion)
    for i in stride(from: 0, to: markers.count, by: 1){
        let marker = markers[i]
        if bounds.contains(marker.position) {
            print("Is present on screen")
            print(marker.position)
        } else {
            // Marker not on the screen
        }
    }
```

This works and when I scroll the map on top of a marker I get the printout.

I've got 30k markers that I'm needing to potentially place onto the map. The markers show up at different zoom levels, and only need to be loaded once the user is able to see them.

The marker is a rounded image view, so as you an imagine loading 30 thousand pictures into a map is a huge task.

I have JSON that I am loading in the Lon/Lat/ImageURL.

Do I need to deinit markers as they leave the screen and init them as they come onto the screen? Are google map annotations reused like a tableview cell? Should I only create the marker once a location from my JSON is in the bounds of the map, or can I create them and only add them to the map once they're in the bounds? What sort of optimization tools should I use?

Thanks for any tips here

Comment: is JSON a .json file or generated from the API?

Comment: JSON file @Fadielse